# Using image as face of character in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a character with a flat head and I would like to apply a texture to the head to be used as face.

In the image below you can see that I have selected the region were I would like to map the texture. It seems to be working fine if I mark the border of the selection as a seam and then I unwrap it. But then the texture will apply to the entire body.

What is the best way to have both a material for the skin but also a texture in the selected region?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: character screen]

Comment: Give the selection other material and apply texture. UVs always affect the whole mesh.

Comment: I will try this approach, thanks!